# How can i exclude rendering an enviroment texture in cycles but keeping all the other settings?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

How can i exclude rendering an enviroment texture in Cycles but keeping all the lighting and reflections that i get from it? like, rendering with the background, but make it black (not transparent)

Already tried to render it as PNG Transparent and then in After Effects add a black background, but what i want is to directly render it on JPEG format with black background to save render time.

[image]

Comment: Is saving as .png and combining it with a black image not an option?

Comment: Yes, i already tried that, but i want it to render as a JPEG because i need to save render time.

Comment: Look at the [nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/66225/30849) in the last image. You can set the camera background independently.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain to me how can i make the light node appear? i never used it before.

Comment: Also, i need to keep an HDRI that makes the lighting look as i need, but apart of it i need to make the background look just black.
It is like, the same to make it Transparent (without any background at all) but without getting any alpha channel and to make it appear black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally what it worked was:

- Unchecking the 'Transparent' option before anything
- Checking 'Use Enviroment' at the Scene Tab
- Most importantly, in the World Tab, uncheck 'Camera'

So with those options the objects will be affected with the background but the background itself will not appear as part of the render.

[image]